# Inline editable with button and dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I would like use inline x-editable with a button.

Same like this sample
http://jsfiddle.net/jjdJX/3/

If I use this with fix selectors like:

```
$('#publicname-change').editable({
```

works fine.

But I have elements and there id's, they come from the database, and I can not say how much id's I have and what there name are.

I use now a button. If I click this button (like in the sample) then I get also the id from this field, what I need.

If it is possible I can use  $('#'+myselectorId).editable({

If the DOM load ok then I can find all there id's

If I click on the button then I can get the ID from that editable field what I need.

Normal I have to fix the selectors like:

```
 $('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
   });
```

I am looking for a way to call this editable by click on the button and with a dynamic id (selector) like this:

```
$('#'+myselectorId).editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

Best regards.

Juergen

Answer (score 0):

May work since you look for inputs :

```
var inputObj=[];
$("input").each(function(index){
    thisID=$(this).attr("id");
    thisNAME=$(this).attr("name");
    inputObj[index]={"thisID":thisID,"thisNAME":thisNAME};
    console.log("thisID: "+thisID+", thisNAME: "+thisNAME);
});

var inputTotal="";
for(i=0;i<inputObj.length;i++){
    inputTotal += JSON.stringify(inputObj[i]);
}
console.log(inputTotal);
```

Run it in all your pages.
Console.log may be enought.

it gives this kind of result:
[image]

**Other cool thing is this sotfware : [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) completely free** AND really usefull to search in big web dev folder**s** by keyword for file title and file content + regexp.

A must!

;)

Answer (score 0):

first, thanks for your help and answere.

Maybe i have first describe the problem no correct...

i would like work with jquery x-editable plugin....
on my test-webside works this plugin fine... but now i load a dynamic side... they include some tabs... the count of tabs are depend how much tabs are in the database...

i hope the code make that a little more clear to understand....

```
     <?php


     echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs navSub">';
   while($row       = mysqli_fetch_object($result_4)){
    $active = "";
    if ($row->active ==1){
        $active = "active";
    }
    echo '<li class="'.$active.'" id="'.$row->liBoxId.'" 
     typeGroup="'.$row->typeGroupId.'">';
    echo '<a href="#"'.$row->divBoxId.'" class="editable shortDesc"   name="shortDesc" id="'.$row->editableid.'" onclick="request(7,1,1, 1, 0,0, '.$row->typeGroupId.')" data-toggle="tab">';
         echo ''.$row->tabTitle.'';
          echo '<span class="badge badge-success">&nbsp;</span>';
         echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
};

        echo '<button type="button" id="editTitle" class="btn btn-white btn-info">';
        echo '<i class="blue ace-icon fa fa-pencil  center bigger-110"></i>';
       echo '</button>';
       echo '</ul>';

      ?>

     <script>

           $( document ).ready(function() {
           $('.shortDesc').each(function() {
           $('#'+this.id+'').editable('disable', true);
             });
       });



           jQuery(function($) {

            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
            $.fn.editableform.loading = "<div class='editableform-loading'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x light-blue'></i></div>";
            $.fn.editableform.buttons = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info editable-submit"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i></button>'+
                                        '<button type="button" class="btn editable-cancel"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></button>'; 



         }

           $('#editTitle').click(function(e){  
                var id = $("ul.navSub li.active").attr('id');               
                id = "editable-"+id;
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('#'+id+'').editable('enable', true);
                //$('#publicname-change').editable('toggle');
        },
        $('#'+id+'')
            .editable({
                type: 'text',
                name: 'shortDesc',
                data: {oper:'editDetail'},
                url: 'incl/asedScripts/ased_updateTitle.php',
                success: function(data,response, newValue) {
                    if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg;

                }
         });    
     );
     </script>
```

i am not sure if is possible on editable with the id they i get from a jquery-call....

```
$('#'+id+'')
            .editable({
```

best regards and thanks for any help

Juergen